# Geth vs OpenEthereum full node size

Tags: go-ethereum

I am deciding whether to start a full node, so I researched the storage size I need for hosting it.

https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault shows the size of an Ethereum full node on Geth and on OpenEthereum. I can't understand why a Geth node takes up 633 GB and an OpenEthereum node only 371 GB. Why is there such a big gap from the two. Am I missing something?

Comment: Figured it out? Was just asking myself the same question, now that the gap is even bigger.